Why does my Spring @Transactional service with multiple EntityManager operations cause an unexpected cache stall?
I have a Spring Boot application using @Transactional for transaction management. Inside one transaction, I'm doing multiple operations using EntityManager, but I’m seeing an odd stall where Hibernate seems to block the queries for no clear reason.
@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Transactional
    public void updateUserData(Long userId, String newData) {
        User user = entityManager.find(User.class, userId);
        
        // Fetching associated data
        List<Role> roles = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.userId = :userId", Role.class)
                                        .setParameter("userId", userId)
                                        .getResultList();
        
        // Updating user data
        user.setData(newData);
        entityManager.merge(user);

        // Additional update which seems to cause a delay
        for (Role role : roles) {
            role.setUpdated(true);
            entityManager.merge(role);
        }
        
        // Flush is supposed to synchronize everything but sometimes causes a long stall
        entityManager.flush();
    }
}



Sometimes the entityManager.flush() takes an unexpectedly long time (seconds), even though the data being updated is relatively small.
I suspect it’s related to the internal caching or dirty checking that Hibernate is doing, but I’m not sure why it's happening.


What’s causing the flush() to stall, and how can I diagnose whether Hibernate is holding up due to caching or some internal lock?

Is there a better way to batch these operations in a single transaction without running into such stalls?


I’ve tried to run this with both @Transactional and manual transactions, but the issue persists.

You need to use profiler.

Don't call merge and don't call flush it isn't needed in the first place. Why aren't the roles part of the User in the first place and update them there. Currently you issue more queries then needed.
